# Laravel DELETE request as API

Tags: laravel-4, restful-url

When you want to delete an item from the db, I know that you can use `/resource/{id}` and use the `contrller@destroy` action.

What is the advantage of passing a parameter in the URL as oppose to send a DELETE request and pass the parameter `$id` via an `Input`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do both, but the first method (using the dedicated `/resource/{id}` URL) is following the RESTFUL design pattern. [Here is a very good video on that](http://vimeo.com/17785736).

To highlight some important points:

- We avoid verbs in URLs, unless they're used for very specific actions. We should try to use nouns instead if it's possible, so a url like `/resource/delete`is not advisable.
- When someone used to the REST way of communicating with an API uses 'DELETE' on the `/resource` url, he/she expects to delete ALL resources. If he/she uses it on `/resource/{id}`, then only that specific item should be removed.

Hope this made sense =)

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense! Thanks